# Package to draw graph visualization with auto layout

Tags: reactjs, visualization, graph-visualization

I am working on a React project and I need to implement a graph visualization that automatically arranges nodes in a tree-like structure. I am looking for a package that provides an auto layout functionality specifically for graph visualization in React.

What I want is something graph like this

```
             Node1
               |
    Node2a \   |   / Node2d
    Node2b - Node2 - Node2e
    Node2c /   |
               |
             Node3
               |
               |  / Node4a
             Node4- Node4b 
               |  \ Nodec
               |
             Node5
               |
             Node6
```

I want the parent nodes to be in the center and number of subnodes can increase and can have sub sub nodes

I have explored some options like react-d3-tree and react-tree-graph, but I would like to know if there are any other recommended packages that meet my requirements.

Comment: try cytoscape js

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend D3.JS,
Here you can find a link for tree charts

> http://christopheviau.com/d3list/gallery.html#visualizationType=tree

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).